# principal components are not perpendicular to the object surfaces

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have applied PCA on a set of points which represents an object. But the result is not perpendicular to the object surfaces(i.e the eigenvectors are not perpendicular to the surface of the objects). Because of which I am not able to calculate real dimensions of the object.
Any idea about principal components?.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first picture shows the small rectangular object next red axis,I want it to be perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be?

Comment: Can you add some example code to your question? Some example data would help too.

Comment: @DonReba I know for the given amount points , result is what i have got. But I have to make it perpendicular so that i can project the points on to the vectors and calculate the correct dimensions .